# How can i get the names of the audio input/output device without truncation?

Tags: python, pyaudio, pyside6

A list of available input/output devices can be obtained using the code below.

```py
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(0)
numdevices = info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(0, numdevices):
    if (p.get_device_info_by_index(i).get('maxOutputChannels')) > 0:
        print("Output Device id ", i, " - ", p.get_device_info_by_index(i).get('name'))
p.terminate()
```

Output:

```
Output Device id  3  -  Microsoft Sound Mapper - Output
Output Device id  4  -  스피커(Realtek High Definition Aud
Output Device id  5  -  헤드폰(2- MATA STUDIO C10)
Output Device id  6  -  LS24AG30x(NVIDIA High Definitio
```

But I get these names cut into 31 characters like this.
How can i get full-named device list?

I'm developing a desktop application on Pyside6, so I tried QMediaDevices.audioOutputs(),audioInputs() and it brought me an uncut full name. But the device index could not be obtained.

I thought about how to obtain a full name-index pair by comparing the list obtained by get_device_info_by_index with the list obtained as a function of QMediaDevices, but I think it's not cool and there must be a clear way.

Comment: So `audioOutputs()` doesn't respect the same order as the id of PyAudio?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me if I use another host API, such as Windows WASAPI (which btw seems to be the recommended one since it's more modern than the other ones).
You could do something like:

```
import pyaudio

PREFERRED_HOST_API_NAME = 'Windows WASAPI'


def get_api_info(p: pyaudio.PyAudio):
    api_info, api_index = None, 0
    for i in range(p.get_host_api_count()):
        current_api_info = p.get_host_api_info_by_index(i)
        if i == 0:
            api_info = current_api_info
        else:
            if current_api_info['name'] == PREFERRED_HOST_API_NAME:
                api_info, api_index = current_api_info, i
                break
    return api_info, api_index

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
api_info, api_index = get_api_info(p)
api_name = api_info['name']
if api_name != PREFERRED_HOST_API_NAME:
    print(f'[WARNING] "{PREFERRED_HOST_API_NAME}" not available on this system, '
        f'going with "{api_name}" instead')

numdevices = api_info.get('deviceCount')
for i in range(numdevices):
    dev_info = p.get_device_info_by_host_api_device_index(api_index, i)
    if dev_info.get('maxOutputChannels') == 0:
        continue
    print("Output Device id ", i, " - ", dev_info.get('name')) # name is full for me here
```

Explanation is probably that for older Host APIs name length was limited, but haven't checked this, I'm simply going with WASAPI cause it seems the better choice from what I could gather so far - modern, lower latency, more flexible etc (I'm not very familiar with this topic either, just guessing).